# What's 'Explosive Replicator'?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

> *"Missile based weapons have a 50 percent chance of not using a missile."*

What benefits does it add?

Does it mean that enemies missiles have 50% to fail?

Does it effect my ships missiles also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Explosive Replicator affects your missile weapons only - 50% of the time that you fire a missile weapon, your missile count will not go down.

There are obvious benefits to this if you're running a ship with a lot of missile weapons, because it greatly reduces the amount of ammunition you need to keep stockpiled. However, if you are *out* of missiles, you still won't be able to use those weapons - you don't get a 50% chance to 'run on empty'.

Also, as per the [FTL Wiki](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Augmentations):

> Multi-shot weapons (Swarm and the Pegasus Missiles) have the same 50 percent chance of not using a missile in their volley. This is because one missile is used when firing these weapons, even though there are multiple attacks from them.

Your enemies are not directly affected by this augmentation, although they'll be unhappy about the indirect effect of you throwing missiles with greater aplomb.